# How would a Pokéball know that it needs to be transferred to Oak?

Tags: pokemon

In [Episode 13](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP013) Ash catches a Pokémon that would exceed the limit of 6 Pokémon for the first time and therefore it gets transfered automatically to professor Oak. How does this work?

- How does the ball know it's the 7th?
- How does it know it needs to transferred to Oak?

If I were to guess I would think that every Pokéball is linked directly to the Pokédex which is linked to Professor Oak or something. But this doesn't make sense in a lot of ways. Because:

- not every trainer has a Pokédex
- not every trainer is linked to some professor (I think)

Also what would happen if Ash physically went to Oak, grab some of his Pokéballs (with Pokémon) and walked out?

Comment: See also http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/29203/13855 "Why does Pokemon have a six Pokemon limit?"

Comment: The scene with Damian in *Charmander, The Stray Pokemon* implies that there may be a way around the limit. http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fyk3zXXAnVc/U3EotH14xSI/AAAAAAAABrE/uLoITc0M3E0/s1600/vlcsnap-2014-05-12-21h01m19s76.png

Comment: Also, Team Rocket has on occasion snagged multiple Pokéballs (I recall them having bags of them in an Indigo League episode). So proximity to other Pokéballs isn't what triggers it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an explanation on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball):

> Poké Balls are able to communicate with a Trainer's Pokédex, as the system updates itself with information on newly-caught Pokémon, and keeps track of how many Pokémon the Trainer has with them. If a Trainer catches a new Pokémon with the full six already with them, the Pokédex will automatically send the newly-caught Pokémon in its Poké Ball to the Pokémon Storage System that the Trainer is using.